# Backbone.js and JQueryUI Dialog - events not binding

Tags: backbone.js, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to use Backbone.js to in a JQuery Dialog.  I've managed to get the dialog to render and open, but it doesn't seem to be firing my events.  I've added a test event to check this, and clicking it doesn't have the expected result.

I've tried following the instructions on this [blogpost](http://backbonefu.com/2011/08/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-ui-modals/), regarding delegateEvents, but nothing it made no difference.  No errors are thrown,  the events just don't fire. Why is this?

```
Slx.Dialogs.NewBroadcastDialog.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click .dialog-content": "clickTest"
    },
    clickTest : function () {
        alert("click");
    },
    render: function () {
        var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(this.template);
        var renderedContent = compiledTemplate();

        var options = {
            title: Slx.User.Language.dialog_title_new_message,
            width: 500
        };
        $(renderedContent).dialog(options);
        this.el = $("#newBroadCastContainer");
        this.delegateEvents(this.events);
        return this;
    },
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.template = $("#newBroadcastDialogTemplate").html();
        this.render();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try this. I had to refactor your code a bit hope you will get the idea

```
Slx.Dialogs.NewBroadcastDialog.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:"#newBroadCastContainer",
    template:$("#newBroadcastDialogTemplate").html(),
    events: {
        "click .dialog-content": "clickTest"
    },
    clickTest : function () {
        alert("click");
    },
    render: function () {
        var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(this.template);
        var renderedContent = compiledTemplate();
        $(this.el).html(renderedContent).hide().dialog(this.options.dialogConfig);       
        return this;
    },
    initialize: function () {
    }
});
```

Instantiate and render outside the View definition

```
var myDialog = new Slx.Dialogs.NewBroadcastDialog.View({dialogConfig:{title: Slx.User.Language.dialog_title_new_message,width: 500}});
myDialog.render();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be due to me assigning this.el when I should have been assigning this.$el

This worked perfectly:

```
Slx.Dialogs.NewBroadcastDialog.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#newBroadcastContainer",
    events: {
        "click .clicktest": "clickTest"
    },
    clickTest : function () {
        console.log("click");
    },
    render: function () {
        var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(this.template);
        var renderedContent = compiledTemplate();

        var options = {
            title: Slx.User.Language.dialog_title_new_message,
            width: 500
        };

        this.$el = $(renderedContent).dialog(options);
        return this;
    },
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.template = $("#newBroadcastDialogTemplate").html();
        this.render(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had two codebases on one of the code base I was able to bind events by assigning the dialog to this.$el however in the other codebase this somehow did not work.  I add the following line this.el = this.$el;
to the code and it is working now. however I am still not able to figure out why it was working in one codebase and not the other and why assigning $el to el got it to work.