# Backbone.Js - what's the difference between el and $el?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I've been stuck for the whole afternoon on [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638802/backbone-js-and-jqueryui-dialog-events-not-binding/10640233#10640233) which I eventually solved.  It turned out I was assigning el instead of $el.

What's the difference between the two and when should I use each of them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-%24el), `$el` is:

> A cached jQuery (or Zepto) object for the view's element. A handy reference instead of re-wrapping the DOM element all the time.

So, `$el` is a cached, jQuery (or Zepto) version of `el`. If you need to use any jQuery or Zepto methods on `el`, you can simply use `$el` instead of wrapping `el` in `$()` each time.

Comment: And you shouldn't assign to `el` or `$el`, you should use [`setElement`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement).