# Adding OO to jQuery.dialog()

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I am developing a web page which contains many [jQuery dialogs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).

While my code works in principal, I noticed it soon got "dirty", and I feel a strong urge to clean up the code and make it more OO-like.

The main issues with my code are:

- no dialog-specific state (i.e. set of variables)
- no dialog-local event handlers
- dialog-specific functions are global

Which approaches and solutions exist to make jQuery dialog more OO-like, as in Delphi and WinForms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following can help you:

> - no dialog-specific state (i.e. set of variables)

You can use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to associate state with the augmented element, as with any element:

```
$("#yourDialog").dialog({
    // your options...
}).data("yourData", {
    some: "state",
    associatedWith: "thisElement"
});
```

---

> - no dialog-local event handlers

What you mean by `dialog-local` is not clear, but dialog widgets do emit events, and you can of course bind different handlers to events triggered on the inner elements of different dialog widgets.

---

> - dialog-specific functions are global

They're not actually global (they're part of the `$.fn` namespace), but I understand having to call `dialog()` on the augmented element every time can be seen as unnecessarily heavy.

That syntax, however, is only a bridge, a way to access the widget's methods more suited to jQuery's idioms. You can obtain a reference to the widget itself using, again, `data()`, then invoke its methods directly. For instance:

```
$("#yourDialog").dialog("open");
$("#yourDialog").dialog("close");
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var dialogWidget = $("#yourDialog").data("dialog");
dialogWidget.open();
dialogWidget.close();
```

***Update:*** From jQuery UI 1.9 onwards, [the `data()` key becomes the widget's fully qualified name, with dots replaced by dashes](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys). Therefore, the code above becomes:

```
var dialogWidget = $("#yourDialog").data("ui-dialog");
dialogWidget.open();
dialogWidget.close();
```

Using the unqualified name is still supported in 1.9 but is deprecated, and support will be dropped in 1.10.

Comment: Thanks, Frederic. The wording "main issues" refers to my current solution that I intend to fix, and are not meant to refer to jQuery.dialog in general.

Comment: Ah, then I hope this answer will help you with these issues (if you clarify what you mean by `dialog-local event handlers`, I might be able to improve that part).

Comment: In order to understand your answer ("$.fn" etc.) I needed to go through the jQuery core, especially widget.js and a couple of other files, and I had a *revelation*. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with this, but as I understand it, JS frameworks like [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) can help you with this.

Check out this post to see how this guy is using it:
[Backbone.js and JQueryUI Dialog - events not binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638802/backbone-js-and-jqueryui-dialog-events-not-binding)

To quote their introduction:

> When working on a web application that involves a lot of JavaScript, one of the first things you learn is to stop tying your data to the DOM. It's all too easy to create JavaScript applications that end up as tangled piles of jQuery selectors and callbacks, all trying frantically to keep data in sync between the HTML UI, your JavaScript logic, and the database on your server. For rich client-side applications, a more structured approach is often helpful.